# Django REST multiple permission class not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have two permission class. IsAuthorGroup will check if the user belongs from the author group and IsOwnerOrReadOnly will restrict the user to performing `post` and `delete` if he is not the object's owner.

But the problem is anyone from IsAuthorGroup performing `post` and `delete` request event he isn't own of the object.

**How to restrict anyone from IsAuthorGroup** performing `post` and `delete` request if he isn't owner of the object?

here is my code:

```
class IsAuthorGroup(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user and request.user.groups.filter(name='AuthorGroup'):
            return True
        return False


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the blog.
        return obj.author == request.user or request.user.is_superuser 



class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPagination
    lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly & IsAuthorGroup]
```

my **serializer.py**

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author_first_name = serializers.CharField(
        source="author.first_name", required=False)
    author_last_name = serializers.CharField(
        source="author.last_name", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        exclude = ("author", "blog_is_published")
        lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'blog_slug'}
        }
```

Comment: Object level permissions are not checked when creating objects, so I think anyone in that group will be able to post

Comment: @Iain Shelvington thanks for your comment. How I can add Object-level permissions when creating objects so I can restrict anyone to update or delete any object if the object doesn't belong to him.

Comment: Updates to existing objects are done via the PATCH method method by default, object level permissions should work there. As for creation, I think you may have to do this in the serializer as a custom validation method for the `author` field, the current user should be accessible via `self.context['request'].user`

Comment: @Iain Shelvington I am new in django. I would be grateful to you if you post the answer.